# ECS Cross-Account deployment using AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

We have a Build account(AccountA) that is hosting all the AWS codepipelines(with source and Build current), planning to use codeDeploy for ECS deployment(ECS cluster is on Account B), I'm not sure whether to create CodeDeploy deployment group in Account A or Account B? How do we do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the CodeDeploy should be in **Account B**.

The cross-account setup requires a bit of exercise and  it can't be fully done in AWS Console. The most important and probably the most confusing part is setting up all the **cross-account** IAM roles that are required for that.

Below are some **AWS resources** that should help with this task:

- [Deploy an application in a different AWS account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-cross-account.html)
- [Building a Secure Cross-Account Continuous Delivery Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/)
- [Create a pipeline in CodePipeline that uses resources from another AWS account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html)